# How to use Vector layer with MapBox style JSON in OpenLayers 8

Tags: openlayers, mapbox-vector-tile, ol-mapbox-style

I would like to use Mapbox JSON style with Vector tile source in OpenLayers v8.2 + Openlayers-Mapbox-Style (olms).

The style is very simple, but it doesn't work. I checked on in my browser's Network tab and it seems the tiles downloaded successfully, but my map is blank. It shows nothing. There is no error message on the console.
Maybe my style JSON is wrong?

How can I fix this?

Below is my code:

```
let style_json = {
  "version": 8,
  "name": "railways",
  "sources": {
    "railways3857": {
      "type": "vector",
      "tiles": [ "http://127.0.0.1:7800/railways3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf" ]
    }
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "railways3857",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "railways3857",
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#8cadbf",
        "line-width": 1
      }
    }
  ]
};

var layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
});
olms.applyStyle(layer,style_json);


const map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [layer],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          constrainResolution: true,
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([16, 46]),
          zoom: 14,
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Each entry in the layers array in the style needs a "source-layer" property which matches a "layer" property in the features from the tiles, for an example see https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tiles-mwzxkx?file=/main.js

If you do not know the required value you could use your tile url in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-info.html to find what is needed.